# electronic interference generated by blood?

Tags: signal, noise, interference

Hi so i made a little electrical signal detector that can detect electrical interference/noise(for example putting it near a light or plug makes it squeal). I was messing around with it and noticed it picked up a signal near the right elbow of almost everyone I know. Is there some sort of field generated by the blood moving? Also no one I tested was left handed, not sure if this has to do with the signal because everyone was right handed. The people I tested did not have cell phones with them at the time and it cannot detect most RF anyway, only things such as magnetic fields, or other such fields that can induce a larger current. Also, I tested this on my cat and it goes off weakly near his chest.

[image]

Comment: I suspect it was some other effect.

Comment: Schematic of your circuit?  Sounds like a pretty major leap to come to that conclusion.

Comment: Before you rush to patent your handedness detector, you have the opportunity to do some well controlled experiments. Control the ambient electric field, by going into a grass field a mile from any power line, and then line up your selection of left and right handed volunteers.

Comment: ...do your test subjects wear watches on their right hands?

Comment: Maybe they had their cellphones in their right pocket and the body/arm made a decent antenna?

Comment: Blood also contains iron, but I doubt that has much relevance with the real reason his circuit is doing anything. Still, keep searching. Some really amazing [inventions](http://www.visionaware.org/blog/visionaware-blog/googles-prototype-smart-contact-lens-measuring-blood-glucose-levels-for-people-with-diabetes-1418/12) were created "on the edge" of popular conception.

Comment: OK so i'm gonna try answer some of these questions so 1. i'm trying to draw a schematic, its a tiny circuit and only involves 5 components but i'm busy 2. only one of them had a watch 3. I would a Faraday cadge work? i'm in a big city so it might be hard to get to a empty field 4. I had them put there cell phones somewhere else while i tested them. Another thing I forgot to mention is that prior to exercising the signal coming off of there elbows was weaker

Comment: "Electrical signal detector" is a meaningless description.  What exactly does it detect? How? What frequencies? Amplitudes? Without this and probably a schematic, this is not a question, just a bunch of hand waving.

Comment: I'm not sure what it detects still, as I said, I was just messing around making circuits. I have just made a schematic i will be putting it up soon.

Comment: this is the link to the [schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_r5sHgDUwmlTEM5a0tDREpUaG8/view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since no one else has responded...

Your circuit is just a Darlington triplet (well, I kind of made that name up since it's a Darlington pair with one extra level.  A Darlington pair can often have enough gain to act as a touch switch just from the tiny current that can be conducted across your finger, so a triplet could have an obscene amount of gain (theoretically over one million for the 2N2222), possibly even enough that it picks up current induced in your antenna by your body's electrical pulses.  I think that your elbow has a large nerve bundle running through it near the surface (your funny bone is a nerve, right?), so maybe that's what's its reading...

Edit: Also, I'm totally not saying not to keep experimenting with it; just what my expectation of what is probably happening ( and I'm kind of dumb anyway :P )

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I had no idea what that kind of circuit that was :) I will test this with other nerves